# Basic usage of pickle from python

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to learn how to use pickle, a serialization feature in Python. I have write these 3 basic programms:

1rst programm:

```
import pickle

# An arbitrary collection of objects supported by pickle.
data = {
    'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
    'b': ("character string", b"byte string"),
    'c': set([None, True, False])
}

with open('data2.txt', 'wb') as f:
    # Pickle the 'data' dictionary using the highest protocol available.
    pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

2nd programm:

```
import pickle

data = None

with open('data2.txt', 'rb') as f:
    # The protocol version used is detected automatically, so we do not
    # have to specify it.
    data = pickle.load(f)


data['name'] = 'John'

with open('data2.txt', 'ab') as f:
    # Pickle the 'data' dictionary using the highest protocol available.
    pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

3rd programm:

```
import pickle

data = None

with open('data2.txt', 'rb') as f:
    # The protocol version used is detected automatically, so we do not
    # have to specify it.
    data = pickle.load(f)


print(data)
```

The idea of the whole test is to see how pickles works. I create a dict, add some values and "pickled" them to a file. Then in another module, I "unpicked" the data and add some another key, value to the dict and "pickled" it again to the same file. Finally, in the third module, I "unpicked" the dict and print it and I can't see the data added in the second module. Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because you are trying to _append_ to the file in the second program, instead of overwriting it. Try changing `'ab'` to `'wb'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my idea is to append or Add information not to overwrite it

Comment: You can add information to the dict and keep the old values, but you need to overwrite the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, i came to the same conclusion

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the file but when you read the dictionary into `data` variable, you read the whole dict object and then you are rewriting the whole dict with the new variable. This is equivalent to appending.

You need to change the `ab` to `wb` in the second program.

```
with open('data2.txt', 'ab') as f:
    # Pickle the 'data' dictionary using the highest protocol available.
    pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

You can read the documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump

It clearly specifies that files should be opened in the write binary mode.